# How to fix routes configuration for the gce ingress?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

The ingress calls random services on requests, and also it calls the root (/). I need ingress to call the specified in the configuration service and send the full path to the service (I use MVC pattern so I need to provide the application with the full path to resolve the correct controller)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whatever
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-static-ip-name"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-tls-secret
    hosts:
      - whatever.my-awesome-project.com
  rules:
  - host: whatever.my-awesome-project.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/whatever
        backend:
          serviceName: whatever-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api/not-whatever
        backend:
          serviceName: not-whatever-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /images/*
        backend:
          serviceName: not-whatever-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your question:

1) you are trying to use `rewrite-target` with `gce` ingress --> this wont work. [rewrite-target](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite) is a nginx ingress controller feature. Btw starting from 0.22.0 version you should [use](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite#rewrite-target) `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"` instead of `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"`

2)The annotation add-base-url was removed in 0.22.0. And this is also was nginx annotation, not gce. More info [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3244) an [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/3174).

3)Also I believe you dont need `rewrite-target` annotation if you would like to have correct path

From my pow there should be something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whatever
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-static-ip-name"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-tls-secret
    hosts:
      - whatever.my-awesome-project.com
  rules:
  - host: whatever.my-awesome-project.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/whatever
        backend:
          serviceName: whatever-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api/not-whatever
        backend:
          serviceName: not-whatever-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /images/*
        backend:
          serviceName: not-whatever-service
          servicePort: 80
```

A lot of things depends on what ingress and version you use. Do you have a possibility to move to nginx?

Comment: I guess the question only asks for a "gce" based solution. So it is irrelevant to add a "nginx" solution.